How to reduce a DropdownMenu width to its minimun in Flutter
In my project, there is a material DropdownMenu with only little text like "kg", "lb"...
I'd like to reduce its size to the minimum, but if the width property is set to less than 90, the text is written in 2 lines.
So how to efficiently reduce the inner space between text and arrow which increase dropdown with?
Thank you
I could use another library, but I want to know if there exists a solution for further projects.

https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2

yes @Ask, that's what I finally had to do

I filed a bug on an issue similar to this, previously. Perhaps your problem is related and the issue hasn't been solved by the framework? Can you look at the bug to see if it's related?

It's not the same bug, but I also encountered it
